# The @javax.jws.WebMethod annotation cannot be used in with @javax.jws.WebService.endpointInterface element in maven

Tags: web-services, maven

I am trying to create a JWS web service from a WSDL file that's already defined/created by me.
I have followed a two step approach like:

1. wsimport - from "jaxws-maven-plugin" - to create wsdl artifact files - SUCESS
2. wsgen - from "jaxws-maven-plugin" - to compile my SEI and create a war file - FAILED

I am seeing issues with #2. The error is:

**The @javax.jws.WebMethod annotation cannot be used in with @javax.jws.WebService.endpointInterface element in maven**

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**I used this configuration in my pom.xml. Additionally, avoid to use @WebParam for your parameters, in your @Webmethod. Hope this helps you.**

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sei>service.CompanyImpl</sei>
                        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <inlineSchemas>true</inlineSchemas>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```